# Loading an html page using require.js

Tags: requirejs

I am working on a Html app which uses require.js to load the scripts.I have a homepage which is loaded using jquery load().

I would like to know if we can load the html page using require.js.

Answer (score 0):

The text plugin is your friend. See the [text plugin documentation](https://github.com/requirejs/text) or a [blog post on that topic](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2277-Using-the-Text-Plugin-With-RequireJS-To-Load-Remote-HTML-Templates.htm).

Quoting from the former:

```
require(["some/module", "text!some/module.html", "text!some/module.css"],
    function(module, html, css) {
        //the html variable will be the text
        //of the some/module.html file
        //the css variable will be the text
        //of the some/module.css file.
    }
);
```